# after adding migration when try to update-database command in package manager console

Tags: migration

```
Failed executing Db Command (38ms) [Parameters=[], Command Type='Text', Command Timeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [areas] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,`your text`
    [Postal Adress ] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [PostalCode] int NOT NULL,
    [CityID] int NOT NULL,
    [ProvinceID] int NOT NULL,
    [CountryID] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_areas] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_areas_Countries_CountryID] FOREIGN KEY ([CountryID]) REFERENCES [Countries] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_areas_Provinces_ProvinceID] FOREIGN KEY ([ProvinceID]) REFERENCES [Provinces] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_areas_cities_CityID] FOREIGN KEY ([CityID]) REFERENCES [cities] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I am trying to add and update database through package manager console